# JPA JPQL: SELECT NEW with COUNT, GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: java, select, jpa, aggregate-functions, jpql

There are 2 tables / entities: `AppleTree` and `Apples`. An apple tree produces 0...n apples. Each apple is an entity / row of the second table and references the apple tree that has produced it (`ManyToOne`).

I want to generate a "high score" report on the most productive apple trees. It should be ordered by the COUNT column in descending order:

```
APPLE TREE | COUNT(A)
---------------------
10304      | 1000
72020      | 952
31167      | 800
```

In order to handle these results, I created a non-entity bean that combines an AppleTree object and a long value (for COUNT):

```
// constructor
public AppleStats (AppleTree at, long howManyApples) { ... }
```

I want to fetch rows of this combined type using JPQL. My approach is based on the `SELECT NEW` syntax:

```
SELECT NEW foo.bar.AppleStats ( a.appleTree, COUNT(a) AS c )
FROM Apples a
GROUP BY a.appleTree
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Unfortunately it produces quite a few error messages. I think one problem is the column alias for the COUNT value. I use it as I want to sort by this aggregate value. It means no difference whether I use "COUNT(a) AS c" or "COUNT(a) c". It says the arguments were not separated by comma. Moreover, the *"expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL grammar"*. Finally it says *No constructors can be found that match the argument types."*

Is there a way to get my AppleStats result rows? Or do I have to regress to native queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT NEW foo.bar.AppleStats(a.appleTree, COUNT(a.appleTree))
FROM Apples a
GROUP BY a.appleTree
ORDER BY COUNT(a.appleTree) DESC
```

Unfortunately I don't have a JPA platform to test it right now, but the above should fix the syntax problems of the original query. And don't worry about the fact that the `COUNT()` aggregate function appears twice, that's a pretty common idiom when writing queries and any decent optimizer should be able to handle it and perform the operation only once.