# Hibernate group by with counts

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

In SQL I can do something like this:

```
select m.*,sq.c from message m inner join (
  select max(m.id) as id, count(m.id) as c
    from message m group by m.externalid
) sq on sq.id=m.id;
```

i.e. group the messages table, select by max(id) for each group and then return all the columns plus a count.

Can I do this in Hibernate (ideally JPQL) returning the Messages object plus the count value?

Or what's the best alternative - one query to fetch messages and then a separate one for the counts seems like it could go wrong. But I'm reluctant to have to trawl over a List if I can avoid it.

Edit:

This is as close as I can get to the equivalent Apple example from the link in the comments:

```
select new com.example.MessageStat(m, count(m)) from message as m group by m.externalid
```

But it gives this error:

```
ERROR [2018-08-22 11:35:54,600] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: column "message0_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Which I had with the SQL before adding the inner join, but I haven't been able to figure out the equivalent JPQL for that.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477734/jpa-jpql-select-new-with-count-group-by-and-order-by

Comment: Looks like the select new syntax is enough to massage the results I want out of the query, struggling to replicate the query in JPQL though - if I mimic their query postgres complains that m.id isn't in the group by or an aggregate function.

Comment: I've ducked around this now by using a view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA JPQL: SELECT NEW with COUNT, GROUP BY and ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477734/jpa-jpql-select-new-with-count-group-by-and-order-by)

Comment: It's not a duplicate; the accepted answer doesn't work for me.